# Why is the $.each()'s function not executing?

Tags: jquery

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var catArr=[];
    $.get("viewData.php?action=getCat", function(json) {
        if(json.catArr.length>0)
            $.each(json.catArr, function() 
            {
                catArr.push(this.category);
            });
    }, 'json');

    $.each(catArr, function(index, el) {
        console.log(el);
        $("#category_selector").append($('<option>', { 
            value: el,
            text : el
        }));
    });

});
```

I've ensured that the array catArr[] is filled by using console.log(). Here's a screenshot of that:

[image: contents of catArr]

But I don't get any output due to `console.log(el);`. Doesn't this mean that $.each() isn't executing? Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you specify, whats inside `catArr` after filling it up?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi Added a screenshot of the same.

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're fetching data from server, but your javascript runs as soon as it runs the code, it means your `$.each()` is running before the data comes from the server, you should do it like this:

```
$.get("viewData.php?action=getCat", function(json) {
    if(json.catArr.length>0) {
        $.each(json.catArr, function() 
        {
            catArr.push(this.category);
        });

        $.each(catArr, function(index, el) {
            console.log(el);
            $("#category_selector").append($('<option>', { 
                value: el,
                text : el
            }));
        });
    }
}, 'json');
```

> You should manipulate on your data when it receives from server

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SomenathSinha  - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: @SomenathSinha - :D I know, that's OK.!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have your $.each inside your $.get...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var catArr=[];
    $.get("viewData.php?action=getCat", function(json) {
        if(json.catArr.length>0)
            $.each(json.catArr, function() 
            {
                catArr.push(this.category);
            });

        $.each(catArr, function(index, el) {
            console.log(el);
            $("#category_selector").append($('<option>', { 
                value: el,
                text : el
            }));
        });
    }, 'json'); 
});
```

Comment: That worked! But why? catArr is a variable whose scope exists throughout $(document).ready. So why wasn't $.each working?

Comment: $.get executes and goes to the next lines.  when the web request is complete the callback gets called with your data from the get request.  It's not synchronous so your $.each is running before you get the data from the $.get.